# Compare timestamps for a specific group in master table with the respective staging table of the same group

Tags: hive, timestamp, impala

I have a master and staging tables like below in **HIVE**:

[image]

We have two staging tables, let's say which has records coming in for every 10 mins.

for the first time what ever data is present in staging tables is pushed to master table using the below statement.

```
select * from Staging table-1 
union all
select * from Staging table-2
```

from the next time , only if the timestamp_ present in master table  is less than the timestamp_ in staging(i.e the latest record) should be added into master table else no adding.

I.e, timestamp_ should be compared and only if it latest should be added, else no.

and all these tables are created using Create external and Insert statements are used.

I got stuck in how to compare each timestamp of a specific group to that respective staging table.

I'm new to **hive**, please help me.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two options.

Option 1 - if you can add a new column to master table called record_created_by to keep a track which stage is creating the data.
And your insert statement would be like this

```
select s.*, 'stage1' as record_created_by from Staging table-1 s 
Join (select max(timestamp) mxts from master where record_created_by='stage1') mx On timestamp > mxts
union all
select s.*, 'stage2' as record_created_by from Staging table-2 s 
Join (select max(timestamp) mxts from master where record_created_by='stage2') mx On timestamp > mxts
```

Pls note your first time insert statement would be same above sql but without timestamp part. If you have multiple stages, you can add them like this sql.

Option 2 - if you cant change existing structure of master table, then, you can create a new table to keep max date times for each group. Table should be like this

```
stages, mxts
stage1, 2021-01-01 12:30:30
...
```

Then use it in sql like similar to above sql.

```
select * from Staging table-1 s 
Join maxtimestamp On timestamp > mxts and stages='stage1'
union all
select * from Staging table-2 s 
Join maxtimestamp On timestamp > mxts and stages='stage2'
```

And then insert max timespamp into this table everyday after load.

Second options is faster but you need to create and maintain a new table.

Comment: Thank you @Koushik Roy. I got stuck in applying this idea to query. Your answer helped.

Comment: glad it helped...